# When to use $and query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Can someone tell me the difference between these two queries?

```
db.foo.find({ $and: [{a: 1}, {a: {$gt: 5}}]})
```

and

```
db.foo.find({a:1, a:{$gt:5}})
```

EDIT
Ok let me change the question a little bit. Assume the following

```
dev(mongod-2.2.0)>db.foo.insert({UserID: 1, Status:'unread' })
dev(mongod-2.2.0)>db.foo.insert({UserID: 1, Status:'unread' })
dev(mongod-2.2.0)>db.foo.insert({UserID: 1, Status:'unread' })
dev(mongod-2.2.0)>db.foo.insert({UserID: 1, Status:'unread' })
dev(mongod-2.2.0)>db.foo.insert({UserID: 1, Status:'unread' })
dev(mongod-2.2.0)>db.foo.insert({UserID: 1, Status:'unread' })
dev(mongod-2.2.0)>db.foo.insert({UserID: 1, Status:'unread' })
dev(mongod-2.2.0)>db.foo.insert({UserID: 1, Status:'unread' })
```

And I want to find all unread messages for user id 1. Do I do this

```
db.foo.find({UserID:1, Status:'unread'})
```

or this

```
db.foo.find({$and: [{UserID:1},{Status:'unread']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$and` both conditions are taken into account when querying. Without `$and` only the last spec for `a` is considered in the query. This seems to happen with insert from mongo shell also.

In your edited question, I would definitely use `db.foo.find({UserID:1, Status:'unread'})`

Example below:

```
> db.sotest.insert({a : 1})
> db.sotest.insert({a : 2})
> db.sotest.insert({a : 6})
> db.sotest.insert({a : 7})
> db.sotest.insert({a : [1, 7]})
> db.sotest.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50587c0164433af6a99c988f"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50587c0564433af6a99c9890"), "a" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50587c0d64433af6a99c9891"), "a" : 6 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50587c1064433af6a99c9892"), "a" : 7 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50587c1f64433af6a99c9893"), "a" : [ 1, 7 ] }
> db.sotest.find({a:1, a:{$gt:5}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50587c0d64433af6a99c9891"), "a" : 6 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50587c1064433af6a99c9892"), "a" : 7 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50587c1f64433af6a99c9893"), "a" : [ 1, 7 ] }
> db.sotest.find({a:{$gt:5}, a:1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50587c0164433af6a99c988f"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50587c1f64433af6a99c9893"), "a" : [ 1, 7 ] }
> db.sotest.find({$and : [{a:{$gt:5}}, {a:1}]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50587c1f64433af6a99c9893"), "a" : [ 1, 7 ] }
>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one isn't valid because you can't have an object with two properties that have the same name of `a`.  The first one is valid, so that's the difference.

**EDIT**

In your updated question, you definitely want to use:

```
db.foo.find({UserID:1, Status:'read'});
```

as it's the more natural syntax.

Comment: Both queries are valid. I tested them on the mongo shell and both returned the same result

Comment: Maybe valid's not quite the right word since the shell accepts it, but it's non-sensical as the first `a` value is just ignored and what you end up executing is:  `db.foo.find({a:{$gt:5}})`

Comment: Apart from being natural syntax, is there any difference between the two?

Comment: They're functionally equivalent in this case.